Set different images in the same size in a table
I need help for this code, I don't know how to make the image the same size. I tried to put a width but it doesn't work in my website.
If someone has a clue of what I can add or remove to make it even, it will be very nice.
Thank you in advance



<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<div><!-- [if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="75%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#ed7f31">
<w:anchorlock/>
<center>
<![endif]-->
<a style="background-color: #ed7f31; border-radius: 30px; color: #904b1b; display: inline-block; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; width: 200px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">PROGRAMMATION 2</a>
<!-- [if mso]>
</center>
</v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
<h3>MARDI 8 OCTOBRE, A PARTIR DE 9H</h3>
</td>
<td width="50"></td>
<td colspan="4">
<div>

<!-- [if mso]>
<div><!-- [if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="75%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#6cbce0">
<w:anchorlock/>
<center>
<![endif]-->
<a style="background-color: #6cbce0; border-radius: 30px; color: #1c3540; display: inline-block; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 40px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; width: 200px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">PROGRAMMATION 2</a>
<!-- [if mso]>
</center>
</v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->

</div>
<h3>MARDI 8 OCTOBRE, A PARTIR DE 13H30</h3>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
<td width="30"></td>
<td colspan="4" height="10"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href=" https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/portfolio/tendre-memoire/"><img src="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/wp-content/uploads/2024/07/tendre-memoire.jpeg" alt="Tendre mémoire" width="200" height="282" /></a></td>
<td><a href="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/portfolio/la-voix-des-autres/"><img src="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/wp-content/uploads/2024/07/LaVoixDesAutres_Affiche_A4_Noir-724x1024.jpg" alt="La voix des autres" width="200" height="282" /></a></td>
<td><a href="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/portfolio/les-eaux-calmes/"><img src="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/wp-content/uploads/2024/07/affiche-eaux-731x1024.jpg" alt="Les eaux calmes" width="200" height="282" /></a></td>
<td width="50"></td>
<td><a href="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/portfolio/douze/"><img src="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/wp-content/uploads/2024/07/DOUZE_Poster_final_web_010623.jpg" alt="Douze" width="200" height="282" /></a></td>
<td><a href="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/portfolio/avec-lhumanite-qui-convient/"><img src="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/wp-content/uploads/2024/07/avec-l-humanite-qui-convient-4.jpeg" alt="Avec l'humanité qui convient" width="200" height="282" /></a></td>
<td><a href="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/portfolio/il-cammino/"><img src="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/wp-content/uploads/2024/07/70x100-il-cammino-stampa-ok2-1.jpg" alt="Il cammino" width="200" height="282" /></a></td>
<td><a href="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/portfolio/quimporte-la-distance/"><img src="https://www.festivalfilmsocial.fr/wp-content/uploads/2024/07/qu-importe-la-distance.png" alt="Qu'importe la distance" width="200" height="282" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<h3>Tendre mémoire</h3>
</td>
<td>
<h3>La voix des autres</h3>
</td>
<td>
<h3>Les eaux calmes</h3>
</td>
<td width="30"></td>
<td>
<h3>Douze</h3>
</td>
<td>
<h3>Avec l'humanité qui convient</h3>
</td>
<td>
<h3>Il cammino</h3>
</td>
<td>
<h3>Qu'importe la distance</h3>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="20"></td>
<td width="30"></td>
<td colspan="3" height="20"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>




In the snippet all images are the same size. The last two appear smaller because they have some white border around as part of the image

On my website they are not the same size https://epss.fr/evenements/6e-festival-du-film-social

ok, you should probably include in your question and snippet some of your css styles applied to the table and images (.contenu img, .contenu td...), so the question is reproducible and the snippet representative of your issue

Seeing the style.min.css file on your website, you have the following style applied to your table images:
.contenu img {
  height: auto;
}

you could remove the height: auto; and replace it by:
.contenu img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 280px;
}

I used the width/height you set in the inline attributes but you can adjust to whatever you want.
